# Why is this jQuery trigger not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire an event that should then be caught by a binding:

```
var input = $("#input");
input.bind("keypress", function (e) {
    //textarea.attr('name', textarea.textrange('get').position);
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == '@') {
        alert('@');
    }
});
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 64; // # Some key code value

$("#press").click(function () {
    $("#input").val($("#input").val() + '@')
    $("#input").trigger(e);
})
```

When I click the button, I see the character inserted, and the trigger is fired, but the binding never catches it.  What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tt36q/1/

Comment: Why should it catch it? You're listening for a keypress event but triggering a keydown.

Comment: works fine with proper event

Comment: @Juhana - I need to listen to keypress so I can capture the character... do you know how I can trigger this keypress with character from the click() function?

Comment: `var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger the same event that you've bound, and listen for the same property (e.which) as you're passing:

```
$("#input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if ( e.which) === 64) {
        alert('@');
    }
});

var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 64; // # Some key code value

$("#press").click(function () {
    $("#input").val($("#input").val() + '@')
    $("#input").trigger(e);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tt36q/7/)

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 problems with your code. First, you are binding a `keypress` event but your event is a `keydown`.

Also, you check for `keyCode` but change the `which`.

Change those and it work : http://jsfiddle.net/tt36q/4/

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.keyCode = 64; // # Some key code value
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to replace

```
input.bind("keypress", function (e) { ...
```

By

```
input.bind("keydown", function (e) { ...
```